# I have jsp page which data is loaded from a servlet.How I loaded that servlet when user try to refresh the page?

Tags: jsp, ejb-3.0, reload, servlet-3.0, page-refresh

My jsp page load from a servlet. When a user trying to refresh the page I want to reload the servlet. Without adding any button how I reload that servlet when user press F5 or refresh button on the web browser?